# Weird behavior in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I might sound incredible what I'm experiencing right now but I have this code along another operations.

```
double mues1 = 0;
mues1 = (Math.pow((ab/100),2)*tam);
```

Where ab=4, tam=400.

This should give .64, but the variable keeps being 0.0, and it only changes it's value if the operation is bigger than 1.

If I replace the math.pow with ^2, the variable becomes 800.0 no matter which value has 'ab'.

Just to make clear, I'm debugging the code so I know how the value is.

I have restarted eclipse and my computer and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `ab` is an integer and you are performing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

According to integer division, `4/100 = 0`. To get the result `0.04`, declare `ab` as a double.

FYI, the caret character in Java performs a [bitwise xor](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html), so you probably don't want to use that.

Comment: Since we can't see in your snippet how you declare `ab` and `tam` he's probably right.  If you want precision in Java you need to be precise.

Comment: it is a caret.  A carrot is a vegetable.

Answer (score 3):

Is ab and int? If so, you'll need to change `ab/100` to `(double)ab/100` or `ab/100.0`. Otherwise, it will perform integer division which truncate towards 0. In other words 4/100 = 0.

Comment: Also, in Java, the ^ operator means xor, not power.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are dealing with int literals, the value of `4/100 = 0`.  You should try to do this using float literals `4.0/100.0`.

When you try to do `4^100`, you are doing a "bitwise exclusive or", as that is what `^` means in Java.  This is not doing what you think it is, so do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from float/double values being demoted to integer, so any 0.nn gets truncated to 0.

try this:

> mues1 =
>   (Math.pow(((double)ab/100),2)*(double)tam);

or just declare `ab` and `tam` as double